# PHP how to save HTML string into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, html

In response to an API call, I'm getting a full HTML script. Full means it includes HTML CSS and Javascript. Now I have that HTML as string in PHP variable.

```
$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Some Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';
```

Now, what is the best way to save this variable in Database and How?

- As a string with VARCHAR  or TEXT type?
- As a string with Base64 Encoded with VARCHAR or TEXT type?
- As a Binary with BLOB type?

Or any other you would like to suggest(May be Serialize or Pack)?

Comment: In wp they used `addslashes(deslash($content)); `. deslash function written by wp core itself to make it generalize and store it on WordPress database. It helps to work on.

Comment: I hope your users can not access these html data else your leaving your self open for xss attack's

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use base64 encoded data to store in my Database with the BLOB datatype. The boilerplate code is as follow.

```
$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Some Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';
```

To encode data in base64

```
$encodedContent = base64_encode($content); // This will Encode
```

And save the data in database with BLOB. Now after retrieve data, just decode it as follow.

```
$ContentDecoded = base64_decode($content);  // decode the base64
```

Now the value of **$contentDecoded** is the plain HTML.

Comment: I'd also like to know about the downvotes. Why people downvote without pointing out the mistake?

Comment: @e4c5 said it: you increase the storage size in this way

Answer (score 6):

If you base64 encode it you increase the storage size by rougly 30% and you need to decode it each time you display it. Look at the [table structure](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-data-in-wordpress--cms-20567) for Wordpress, the most widely used software that stores html on a mysql database using php. What do they use? LONGTEXT. In your case TEXT is probably better because you probably have a good idea about the size of the page.

Comment: Thanks @e4c5 I'll have a look at this. The link you suggest is more sort of generalized form. But yes I'd have a look how WP deal with this.

Comment: No that was just an example, no need to dig deeper. Just use TEXT but don't bother with base64 encode

Comment: @e4c5 what if the HTML is out of our control? For example if I fetch a random site from the internet, should I somehow encode it before storing it? Would this help to prevent a potential sql-injection?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to avoid sql injection. You should never allow HTML that is outside your control to be saved in the database in the first place, that will leave you wide open to XSS attacks

Answer (score 4):

Store HTML into a variable using `addslashes()` function.

```
$html = addslashes('<div id="intro">
<div id="about" align="left">
<h2 class="bigHeader" dir="rtl"HEADER</h2>
<img src="img/Med-logo.png" alt="" />
<div id="wellcomePage" class="text-left text" dir="rtl">
<p>...some words....</p>
<p>.some words....</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>');
```

After this, form an SQL query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Pages` SET `content`= '".$html."'";
```

and you have to add `stripslashes` when retrieve from DB

Answer (score 1):

you can use base64_encode and store that string into db with text/blob type of field

Comment: Yes... at the time of displaying you need to decode that string

Comment: base64 encode/decode is not needed since BLOBs can hold any kind of data. And encode/decode takes up CPU and memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `TEXT`. Blobs are typically used to store images, audio or other multimedia objects. read more about [bolobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object)

Data type to store HTML in Database would be `TEXT`.

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to store html text in database

```
$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Some Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';

$html = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
```

Comment: Thanks @Manjeet But the function you suggest **mysql_real_escape_string** is deprecated. Also I see this **htmlspecialchars()** function but, is it safe to store big html documents in database? Because I have never seen straight HTML in databases.

Answer (score 0):

See this: I did nothing...

I use it like this ..working just fine and also saving in mysql and also retrieving back properly.

```
    $editorContent = $_POST['textarea'];
    
    $a = $editorContent;
    
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO psd ( psdata) VALUES ( '$a')" );
```

Comment: This just takes the value of the text area and not any special html tags. `<textarea>` tag itself doesn't go to the database... and if you had other tags, e.g. `<em>`, `<strong>`, etc. mixed into the content, I don't think this would take care of saving them.