# How to insert html and javascript code with textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I want to insert html and JavaScript code with textarea field  in my database. Problem is code has inserted but its replaced all double question with backlash. How to insert this code with textarea.

`<div id="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow539" class="TA_cdsratingsonlynarrow"><ul id="Ny62NY" class="TA_links r04zlbt"><li id="jb9xdEapRG" class="sc9nmfeVX"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/tripadvisor_logo_transp_340x80-18034-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a></li></ul></div><script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=cdsratingsonlynarrow&amp;uniq=539&amp;locationId=671932&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=false&amp;shadow=false&amp;display_version=2"></script>`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339415/5894241) answer might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert/inject html and javascript code using textarea input field into the current page.

consider, you've following textarea:

```
<div id="output"></div>
<div style="margin: 25px auto; width: 80%; height: auto;">
    <form id="myform" name="myform">
        <textarea id="mytextarea" name="mytextarea" cols="90" rows="20"></textarea>
        <br> <button type="button" id="mybutton">execute</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, you can add event listener to that above button to extract html and javascript code from the textarea and insert them to the page:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var mytextarea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
            var pattern = /<script>([^]+?)<\/script>/mg;
            var matches, txt = mytextarea.value;
            if (txt) {
                while (matches = pattern.exec(txt)) {
                    if (matches[1]) {
                        var tContent = matches[1].replace(/(\n|\r)+/gm, '');
                        var s = document.createElement('script');
                        s.innerText = tContent;
                        document.body.appendChild(s);
                    }
                }
                txt = txt.replace(pattern, '');
            }
            if (txt) {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = txt;
            }
        });
    });
```