# plain html to mysql after form submit

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

is it possible to store plain html code inside mysql table after submitting a form? For example, I would like to create a new post for my blog using my custom cms in laravel and I want to store all the `<h>, <p>` etc.. elements inside one column.

Comment: Yes, you can store the all the HTML tags, submitted through the form.

Comment: could you tell me how, please?

Comment: You just need to design your schema to store the text and tags you want

Comment: @DominykasČesonis Store the data inside column with type text. It will store all the tags.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](//stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data['name']  = '<h1>'.$request->name.'</h1>';
```

to encode this data use below

```
$name = base64_encode($data['name']);
Post::create(['name'=>$name]);
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338770/php-how-to-save-html-string-into-database